# Read XML file from cpp

Tags: xml, roscpp, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a .xml file, which I need to read.
Searching in Internet, I saw that I could do that with MSXML. But I can't include the library in my program.
Anyone knows how I can do that?
Or is there a other way to read a XML file?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191269/read-xml-file-from-cpp/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend using TinyXML as it is already used by several important packages in ROS (e.g. URDF, rviz, rospack). For an example of how to use TinyXML in compilation, check out the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/7e0ba6c1fc5fab8f99a3a6fbb925fc40e6d683a2/kdl_parser/CMakeLists.txt) file from the [kdl_parser](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl_parser) package. A relatively self-contained example of how to read an xml file is in their [kdl_parser.cpp](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/7e0ba6c1fc5fab8f99a3a6fbb925fc40e6d683a2/kdl_parser/src/kdl_parser.cpp) file.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2